# Unable to retrieve certain information (order history, trading accounts) using coinbase pro api

Tags: node.js, coinbase-api

There seems to be a lot of unnecessary blending of GDAX documentation and Coinbase Pro documentation. I understand the GDAX is going to be deprecated, but some of the code still works.

I am unable to retrieve order information using the Coinbase Pro api. I am using the following URI:

```
https://api.pro.coinbase.com/
```

is this the right URI? When I try to use `https://api.pro.coinbase.com/accounts` or `https://api.pro.coinbase.com/orders` I get `undefined`

Going by the documentation on the Coinbase site isn't helping. Is there a better package/repository out there that I can use?

I'm also seeing a general slow deterioration of the Node.js ecosystem and the functioning of the underlying code, so that might be the issue as well.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to sync the accounts (wallets) associated with coinbase pro account.

Then for each account, you need to get the transaction history:

```
https://api.pro.coinbase.com/accounts/<account id>/ledger
```

Comment: a forward slash is required between `<account id>/ledger`